# Problem with recoding variables with dplyr

Tags: r

I am getting an error message when trying to recode the gender currently coded as 1 or 2 in my dataset to Male and Female.

This is the code I am using

```
nhanes.2017 <- Tchol_cleaned %>%
mutate(Sex = recode_factor(.x = Sex,
`1` = 'Male',
`2` = 'Female'))
```

The error I am getting

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Sex`. i `Sex = recode_factor(.x
> = Sex, `1` = "Male", `2` = "Female")`. x no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "c('labelled', 'integer')"

The Tchol_cleaned dataset
https://ufile.io/fxw8h71v

Comment: Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(Tchol_cleaned))`, without data we cannot tell what's going on.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(Tchol_cleaned)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Tchol_cleaned, 20))`.

Comment: Thanks for the data. The solution is to remove the `.x =` part. And you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks !! Sorry, for the way I presented the question. I will improve next time.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to say without data, but something like this should do the trick.

```
nhanes.2017 <- Tchol_cleaned %>%
          mutate(Sex = case_when(1 ~ "Male", 
                                 2 ~ "Female"))
```